# Sum column value while updating table using sqlbulktools

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, sqlbulktools

I'm using SqlBulkTools nuget package to update several hundred rows of data. The examples I find online involve specifying specific value that's copied to the table.

Is it possible to Add/Sum a value to existing stored value? e.g. lets say a column 'Count' has value 200. I want to update it by 128, is it possible using SqlBulkTools?

Answer (score 0):

The main use case for SqlBulkTools is to simply import data directly into your database, so there wouldn't be any feature or event that lets you directly define operations to be performed during the bulk operation. [BuildPreparedDataTable()](https://github.com/tiagorosendo/SqlBulkTools#buildprepareddatadable) might be what you're looking for, but I've never used it before, so I can't say with confidence.

Instead, your best option would be to modify the data before hooking it up with SqlBulkTools. There are multiple ways you can accomplish this.

1. Forgo SqlBulkTools, and use a stored procedure instead.
2. Direct translation with LINQ.
3. Setup AutoMapper, then create your own IValueResolver.

## Option 1: Stored Procedure

Although not using SqlBulkTools, this is probably the easiest and most efficient option, as you can reference the table you are updating in place.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Add128ToCount
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    UPDATE st SET [Count] = st.[Count] + 128
    FROM dbo.SomeTable st
    WHERE st.LastModifiedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
END
```

For those who need to do some kind of data modification between tables instead of with the same table, create a User-Defined Table Type that matches your table's structure, then add a Table-Valued Parameter to the stored procedure using that type. ([More Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15))

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Add128ToCount
    @TVP SomeOtherTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable
    (
        Name,
        [Count]
    )
    SELECT Name,
        [Count] + 128 AS [Count]
    FROM @TVP;
END
```

## Option 2: LINQ

If you must use SqlBulkTools (if you don't have database access rights, for example), you can accomplish the same thing as Option 1 by using LINQ. ([More Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/data-transformations-with-linq))

```
List<DestType> dest = (from s in source
                       select new DestType
                       {
                           Id = s.Id,
                           Name = s.Name,
                           Count = s.Count + 128
                       }).ToList();
```

## Option 3: AutoMapper IValueResolver

If you only need to do something like this once, this option would be overkill, as there is a lot of setup involved, including configuring AutoMapper and defining the profiles. However, this is a good long term solution in cases where you are working with multiple tables or even multiple databases. For the specific use case here, your profile would look something like this:

```
class SomeTableProfile : Profile
{
    public SomeTableProfile()
    {
        SourceMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
        DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
        CreateMap<SourceType, DestType>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Count, opt => opt.MapFrom<Add128ToCountResolver>());
    }
}
```

Then, you would make a custom IValueResolver, like this:

```
class Add128ToCountResolver : IValueResolver<SourceType, DestType, int>
{
    public int Resolve(SourceType source, DestType destination, int destCount, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source.Count + 128;
    }
}
```

([More About AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html)) ([More About Value Resolvers](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html))